# Who is the other person on the Great Wizard's throne?

Tags: character-identification, the-worst-witch

When Miss Cackle testifies before the Magic Council in S02E08, there's a witch sitting on this large wooden throne along with the Great Wizard. She also has a fancy pointy hat like the Great Wizard, but unlike the other members, who go bare-headed.

[image]

What is this witch's position on the Magic Council? Since, like the Great Wizard, she is sitting on a throne instead of a bench, she must not be an ordinary member of the Magic Council. It seems like the Great Wizard is in charge of the rules for both witches and wizards, so it doesn't seem likely that he has a direct witch counterpart. For instance, is there a rule to have one witch and one wizard head of the Magic Council, in spite of the authority of the Great Wizard over the Witch's Code?

Comment: All of the members are sat on benches, including the Great Wizard. I'm assuming she was just A.N.Other member of the council.

Comment: @Valorum - You changed your mind there? I like the idea of her being his legal counsel; it seems plausible. But look more closely: the Great Wizard is seated on a large brown wooden throne in the center of the gathering, whereas the other members are on white stone benches. It's pretty clear that his central position on a special seat is meant to indicate his authority in the Council, not to mention that this other witch is literally sitting in the same seat as him.

Comment: I figured the council just has x seats. Since it would be unseemly for the other witches and wizards to have to sit on each other's laps, someone shares a bench with the Great Wizard.

Comment: @Valorum - I think they could conjure up an extra seat and let the Great Wizard have his own throne if that were the case.

Comment: I've prodded the writer and the director. Hopefully one of them will weigh in on it. I've also tried to identify the actress without any joy.